# PowerMockito fails intermittently to mock final void method for an abstract class

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, testng, mockito, powermock

I am using TestNG 6.8.8, Mockito 1.9.5 and PowerMock 1.5.4. When I mock a final void method, the test passes sometimes and fails sometimes with error UnfinishedStubbingException.

Is this a PowerMock bug?

```
public abstract class Parent implements Serializable {
  protected abstract void validate();

  public final void validateSomething() {
    // some code here
  }
}

@PrepareForTest({ Parent.class })
public class ParentTest {
  @Test
  public final void testSomeMethod() {
    Parent parentObj = PowerMockito.mock(Parent.class);
    doNothing().when(parentObj).validateSomething();

    TestCodeThatResultsInCallToParentObj.validateSomething();
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.PowerMockitoCore.doAnswer(PowerMockitoCore.java:36)
E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!

        at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.MockitoMethodInvocationControl.performIntercept(MockitoMethodInvocationControl.java:260)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegation and wrap the execution of that class in your class.

```
class ParentWrapper {
    private final Parent delegate;

    ParentWrapper(Parent delegate) { 
        this.delegate = delegate; 
    }

    void validateSth() {
        delegate.validateSth();
    }

}
```

and now you can mock the ParentWrapper without any Powermock.